Merge into tableA from tableB with unknown columns
I am trying to merge columns from tableB to tableA and I'm searching for the best way to do it (Oracle). TableA already has all the columns I need, so I'm using merge into. Tables look like this.
TableA



KeyA
Amount_1m
Amount_2m
Amount_3m
etc...
Amount_30y
Amount_above30y




a
null
null
null

null
null


b
null
null
null

null
null



TableB



keyA
label_sys
amount




a
upto_1m
100


b
upto_2m
150


c
upto_1m
20


a
above_30y
300



I tried to merge columns using casing on label_sys, but it took too much time.
merge into tableA a
 using tableB b
   on a.KeyA = b.KeyA
when matched then 
 update set a.Amount_1m = case when b.label_sys = 'upto_1m' then b.amount,
            a.Amount_2m = case when b.label_sys = 'upto_2m' then b.amount,
            a.Amount_3m = case when b.label_sys = 'upto_3m' then b.amount,
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
            a.Amount_30y = case when b.label_sys = 'upto_30y' then b.amount,
            a.Amount_above30y = case when b.label_sys = 'above_30y' then b.amount;

I assumed that casing was the thing that was time consuming, I pivoting the tableB and then update columns. I did it like this
   merge into tableA a
     using (select * from (
              select * from tableB 
              ) pivot (sum(amount) for label_sys in ("upto_1m" amount_1m, 
                                                     "upto_2m" amount_2m, 
                                                     "upto_3m" amount_3m, 
                                                      ...,
                                                     "upto30" amount_30y, 
                                                     "above_30y" above_30y)

                       )
            )b
       on a.KeyA = b.KeyA
    when matched then 
       update set a.amount_1m = b.amount_1m,
                  a.amount_2m = b.amount_2m,
                            ...;

But the problem with this approach is, that it is not necessary that tableB will have any row with label_sys pivoting to all columns that I want to merge into tableA (I get the error that the columns in tableB is not existing). I was thinking if there is a way that I could check if column exists in tableB, but coludn't think of it.
So I need help. Could you show me how to make the first approach faster. Or how to merge into using pivot, but dealing with "unknown" columns.

In Oracle, double quotes are for (case-sensitive) identifiers and single quotes are string literals. You want to use string literals in the PIVOT because you are trying to match string values in rows (rather than trying to match multiple columns, which would be an UNPIVOT).
MERGE INTO TableA dst
USING (
  SELECT *
  FROM   TableB
         PIVOT(
           SUM(amount)
           FOR label_sys IN (
             'upto_1m'   AS Amount_1m,
             'upto_2m'   AS Amount_2m,
             'upto_3m'   AS Amount_3m,
             'upto_30y'  AS Amount_30y,
             'above_30y' AS Amount_above30y
           )
         )
) src
ON (dst.keyA = src.keyA)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET amount_1m = COALESCE(src.Amount_1m, dst.Amount_1m),
      amount_2m = COALESCE(src.Amount_2m, dst.Amount_2m),
      amount_3m = COALESCE(src.Amount_3m, dst.Amount_3m),
      amount_30y = COALESCE(src.Amount_30y, dst.Amount_30y),
      amount_above30y = COALESCE(src.Amount_above30y, dst.Amount_above30y)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (
    keyA,
    amount_1m,
    amount_2m,
    amount_3m,
    amount_30y,
    amount_above30y
  ) VALUES (
    src.keyA,
    src.amount_1m,
    src.amount_2m,
    src.amount_3m,
    src.amount_30y,
    src.amount_above30y
  );

Note: COALESCE is used to prevent existing data being overwritten by NULL values; if this is not the desired behaviour then remove the COALESCE and use amount_1m = src.Amount_1m, ....
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE TableA (
  KeyA      VARCHAR2(10),
  Amount_1m NUMBER,
  Amount_2m NUMBER,
  Amount_3m NUMBER,
  Amount_30y NUMBER,
  Amount_above30y NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TableA (keyA) VALUES ('a');

CREATE TABLE TableB (keyA, label_sys, amount) AS
SELECT 'a', 'upto_1m',   100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'upto_2m',   150 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'upto_1m',    20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'above_30y', 300 FROM DUAL;

Then, after the MERGE the table contains:



KEYA
AMOUNT_1M
AMOUNT_2M
AMOUNT_3M
AMOUNT_30Y
AMOUNT_ABOVE30Y




a
100
null
null
null
300


b
null
150
null
null
null


c
20
null
null
null
null



fiddle
